# Cannot get deleteRowsAtIndexPaths to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and a scheduler running in the background deleting records from the underlying data object.
Every time an object is deleted I want the table view to update accordingly.

But i keep getting this annoying error message when trying to delete a row from the table view.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason: "Invalid index path for use with `UITableView`.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on `NSIndexPath` in `UITableView.h` if possible."

The code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSMutableArray* files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fileNames];
[files removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[fileNames dealloc];
fileNames = [NSArray arrayWithArray:files];

//[self.fileNames removeObjectAtIndex:row];
[self.tableDraft deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

PS:
I have also tried `[tableView reloadData];` but that has undesired side effects, erasing the selected index.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you considered following the message's advice? Your index path does not contain both a row and a section component. Use [`+[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-SW1) to create the index path object, so that it has the information the table view requires:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

Comment: +1 I agree... it takes longer to post all this on SO than it does to read the error... it specifically tells you what to do and why it's aborting...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this:

> NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex
>   inSection:sectionIndex];

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-1 inSection:0];

CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [objTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [objTableView convertRect:rectOfCellInTableView toView:[objTableView superview]];
```